# How does a programmer know whether code has already been included in a library?

Tags: libraries

I've never used a library before (.dll or .so) and I'm quite new to it all, but how can someone who is writing code know that it has been written before?

Example: suppose someone rediscovered the *quicksort* algorithm and intends to use it in the program (s)he is writing. It would be way better to find the corresponding library and use it instead of rewriting the whole code. But how would one know it's already out there, and how would one (easily) find (the name of) that library?

Comment: I'm sorry but this question makes no sense. How does one find anything? By searching....

Comment: by googling the name of the algorithm and the language you are using.

Comment: You always use some library, at least the standard C library (e.g. `libc.so.6` on Linux)

Comment: Have a look at the header file that comes with the DLL or use depends (for windows) or nm (for Linux, solaris, HPUX or AIX).

Comment: You could find many [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) libraries, e.g. on [freecode](http://freecode.com/) or [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net)

Comment: I understand your confusion... but of course the person reinventing *quicksort* wouldn't even know that (s)he is reinventing it. For that person it's just his/her own idea.
And it would be an impossible task to start reading the header files of all libraries that could possibly be related to whatever you're trying to do, right?
From your answers i deduct that a LOT of double work is being done...

Comment: For this purpose use documentation of libraries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your technical culture will help you avoiding to reinvent the wheel. The more you'll read, the more you'll learn, and the more you'll be aware of what exist.

As a rule of thumb: if you have a need that doesn't sound *that* specific (eg: sorting an array, parsing an xml file, developing a website, ...), it's worth spending time looking at what already exists.

When you start coding, chances are you'll make the mistake of reinventing the wheel, because you won't know what already exist (or you don't the right keywords). But the more you'll work in this field, the less (hopefully) you'll make it.

So, to put it in a nutshell:

- read (books, code, documentation, technical blogs, ...)
- learn
- Upon starting a new project, don't hurry in your IDE, but first, spend time looking at what could be reused